# Can you port-scan a LAN, from outside the LAN?

Tags: network, network-scanners

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scanning A Subnet Externaly](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16850/scanning-a-subnet-externaly)

Is it possible to scan ports on machines in a LAN, from outside that LAN?

For example, I've got machines in my LAN network and want to check them from the Internet. Is it possible?