# What happens when attacker scan a IP that is used by multiple devices?

Tags: network, penetration-test, ip, vulnerability-scanners, network-scanners

Assuming ISP gives only 1 external IP and you have few devices that use this IP. So you will have a router and few PC's with same external IP and different local IP. When all PC's are online and one of them are vulnerable to EternalBlue, Bluekeep or something else. When attacker scans external IP. Will he see that IP is vulnerable even in case if only one PC is vulnerable or it will scan only router IP? Or it will scan only one device that has this IP?

Comment: Does [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19652/) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming ISP gives only 1 external IP and you have few devices that use this IP

That doesn't happen. There's a network address translation in between. Every device has its own IP address.

That NAT device won't just "randomly" forward things to the devices it hides. So, only the NAT device (which you call "router", but it's really not a router, in the networking sense; there's no accessible addresses behind it, from the ISP's point of view) sees the port scan.